# AngularFire - Get a firebaseObject for each item in a firebaseArray ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have an ng-repeat which is connected to a firebaseArray which is an index of a user's doc Ids.
I want to display a list of their docs with additional info for each one, e.g. it's title and description.

My firebase structure is:

```
+users
  - userId1
    -theirDocs
         -docId1: true
         -docId2: true

+docs
  -docId1
      - tile
      - description
      - url
   -docId2
     - etc etc
```

I've tried everything and still can't get this to work, it seems a pretty common use case. I've tried using a function that calls a firebaseObject each time. I've tried using a separate controller. I've tried a directive, I've even tried using firebase.utils library (I think out of date now).

Can anyone recommend the best way to do this using AngularFire? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to see a code snippet as to fully understand what you've tried first of all, as it's difficult to determine where the issues lie. That being said, as long as your rules are not preventing this, you may need to wait for the data to download using $loaded function beforehand.

**EXAMPLE**

This example is clearly available by following this [link](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#loaded-1), yet here is an example for further clarity:

```
var yourFirebaseReference = firebase.database().ref("REPLACE WITH YOUR FIREBASE BRANCH HERE");
var data = $firebaseArray(yourFirebaseReference);
data.$loaded().then(function(x) {
    console.log(data) // Example, you can do what you want with your 'data' now as the data has loaded
    x === data; // true
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'll add it now. Was really keen to understand what would be the best practice way to do this with angularfire though, to solve this type of query

Comment: Providing the $loaded function solves your problem, this is due to the time delay of waiting for the dàta to load from the server. Hope this helps solve your problem and please accept the answer if so.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thanks so much! I just made a operate controller to use for list items, then made sure to use $loaded then apply it to a scope variable and it works perfectly!   Also I'm new here, not sure how to accept an answer...

Comment: That's great news - asynchronous programming at its best. Please just click on the tick symbol next to my answer stated above to formally accept it. Glad to help!

Comment: Stuck on the same problem - what is the answer provided here, any chance of some code?

Comment: MikeT - Just added a simple example above for you. Hope it helps!